# Remote logging with rsyslog - Cannot load module lmnsd_gtls.so

Tags: rsyslog

I have 2 servers and an office NAS on which I want the two servers to dump their logs. Only 1 server is successfully logging to the NAS. The other server continues to produce this error message in /var/log/messages:

```
May 16 09:01:01 elmer rsyslogd-2068: could not load module '/usr/lib64/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', rsyslog error -2078
 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2068 ]
```

Both servers are running CentOS 7 (4.0.2-x86_64), and both servers have rsyslog-gnutls installed, with 1 minor exception (see below):

```
Installed Packages
Name        : rsyslog-gnutls
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 7.4.7
Release     : 7.el7_0
Size        : 33 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : TLS protocol support for rsyslog
URL         : http://www.rsyslog.com/
License     : (GPLv3+ and ASL 2.0)
Description : The rsyslog-gnutls package contains the rsyslog plugins that provide the ability to receive syslog messages via upcoming syslog-transport-tls IETF standard protocol.
```

**Note that I DO notice a difference in the "From Repo" line** ... for the server that is successfully logging to the NAS, the "From Repo" line says "`updates`" and for the server that is giving off this error message, the "From Repo" line says "`base`".

Both servers have the exact same rsyslog.conf configuration:

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/logging-cert.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls # use gtls netstream driver
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # server is NOT authenticated
*.* @@my-remote-NAS.com:51415
```

Both servers have the same exact file for /etc/ssl/logging-cert.crt, and that file has the same permissions on both servers.

Most results on Google suggest to make sure rsyslog-gnutls is installed, which it is. I'm pulling my hair out. Help!

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to update the other server.

Comment: Yum update doesn't show any updates on either server available for this package.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this [mail thread](http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2011-April/013264.html), it is probably caused by a certificate error from gnutls (which in turn prevents the module from loading). I had a similar problem and was able to resolve it by providing a correct certificate. As one of your server is working, the other not, check if the certificate you provided via

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/logging-cert.crt
```

are identical. Getting the right cert should resolve the issue.